# How do I change the icon for a Windows 7 taskbar group?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

One of the programs I use, Coot, is launched from a batch script, which sets some environment variables, which then launches a program that prints to a console and in-turn launches the program window.  An irritating side-effect of this seems to be that when Windows 7 shoves the console and window into the same taskbar group, it uses the icon from the console, a generic window.

[image]

Is there some way I can make my taskbar show the Coot (bird)?